# Parse Order 2.6.1 and SafeCracker

Tags: safecracker

I recently upgraded to 2.6.1 and I am running into an issue that seems like it could be parse order related, I have the following code that was working before the upgrade.

```
{if segment_3=="summary"}
     {exp:safecracker channel="jobs"
          return="jobs/application/thanks/ENTRY_ID/{username}/{current_time format="%Y-%g-%d_%H-%i"}" 
          {if segment_4 != "new"}entry_id="{segment_4}"{/if}  
          preserve_checkboxes="yes" 
          include_jquery="yes" 
          safecracker_head="yes" 
          class="safecracker" 
          author_only="yes"}
      {/exp:safecracker}
 {/if}
```

The global {username} variable is returning the encoded "%7Busername%7D" opposed to actually showing the username.  I tested the {username} global variable inside the safecracker loop and outside of it and it works - just is not parsing in the parameters section of safecracker.

Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `{username}` global variable is parsed early enough for it to be used within a parameter as you have there.

A couple solutions:

1) You could use Rob Sanchez' [Mo' Variables](https://github.com/rsanchez/mo_variables) add-on, which adds early parsed member variables.

2) Is the username really necessary within your return URL? Since you are redirecting to the ENTRY_ID, you should be able to pull the username from the author of that entry within the template you're directing to. Within the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag, the `{author}` and `{author_id}` variables are available.

Comment: I am also using profile:edit and was able to use a corresponding field in the members channel created with PE.  Thanks for the help Jeremy.

Comment: That works too! Glad to help.